# PHP echo wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, echo

Hi I am trying to `echo` The Name of the Product from the `Product Table` but Instead It `echo` the Name from the `Category table` instead. 
Is they a way to stop this apart from changing the name from one of the 2 tables?

```
Table: Product

   Pid     Name
    1      man
    2      woman
    3      child


Table: Category

  CatID    Name       Pid
    1       pen        1
    2       pen        1
    3       pencil     2
    3       red_pen    3


Table: active_product

  ATpid  size  pid   price
    1     12    1     10
    2     14    2     15
    3     16    3     20
    4     18    4     30
```

PDO:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT Product.Name, Category.Name, size, Price
    FROM active_Product, Product, Category
    WHERE Product.ProdID ='$item_id'
    AND size = '$size '
    AND Category.Name = '$pcategory'
    Limit  1");
$stmt->bindParam('$item_id',$item_id);
$stmt->bindParam('$size',$size); 
$stmt->bindParam('$pcategory',$pcategory); 
$stmt->execute();
foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ){
    $product_name = $row["Name"];
```

Comment: @A.S. Roma new question

Comment: `Name` is ambiguous. You need to use `SELECT Product.Name as Name`, or better, `SELECT Product.Name as ProductName` and then do `$product_name = $row['ProductName'];`

Comment: Also, that code shouldn't work. You will get a "Name is ambiguous" error if you run it. Not to mention `Name` is not a table you are selecting from, so `Name.Category` would fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product.Name AS PName, Category.Name AS CName, size, price 
FROM active_product, Product, Category 
WHERE Product.pid=1 AND size=10 AND Name.Category="pen" Limit 1
```

Then in your PHP, do this:

```
$product_name = $row["PName"];
```

So your final product should be this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT Product.Name AS PName, Category.Name AS CName, size, Price
    FROM active_Product, Product, Category
    WHERE Product.ProdID ='$item_id'
    AND size = '$size '
    AND Category.Name = '$pcategory'
    Limit  1");

...

foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ){
    $product_name = $row["PName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the values, PHP does not use the table to qualify the name.  It will use the last value, so `Name` will refer to the category name.  You can reverse the order you select `Product`/`Category` names, but it makes more sense to use an alias.

```
SELECT Product.Name AS proName, Category.Name AS catName

$product_name = $row['proName'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the corrections already mentioned, you are not binding any variables, you are simply injecting them in your sql statement.

You should use:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT Product.Name as productName, Category.Name as categoryName, size, Price
FROM active_Product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.ProdID =:item_id
AND size = :size  AND Category.Name = :pcategory Limit  1");
$stmt->bindParam(':item_id',$item_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':size',$size); 
$stmt->bindParam(':pcategory',$pcategory);
```

Instead of:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT Product.Name, Category.Name, size, Price
FROM active_Product, Product, Category
WHERE Product.ProdID ='$item_id'
AND size = '$size '  AND Category.Name = '$pcategory' Limit  1");
$stmt->bindParam('$item_id',$item_id);
$stmt->bindParam('$size',$size); 
$stmt->bindParam('$pcategory',$pcategory);
```

Note that you need to use the `:` instead of the `$` and that you do not need to quote your variables.

Comment: because this query is for a shopping basket the '$size' is define above the code. but if it wasn't for that i normally use the way you just point out. cheers

Comment: just took a really good looks at it now and i see why that wasn't the best approach... because of sql injection. Thanks again